# How can I compare the column of two 2-dim array without any third-party libraries?

Tags: python, arrays

I can compare the rows of two 2-dim array simply by:

```
arr1[1] == arr2[1]
```

But how about columns? Is there any convenient function to do that?

Comment: Sorry, can I know the reason for the -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over the "rows" and check that `all` elements of the "column" are equal to the corresponding elements in the other array:

```
all(row_a[1] == row_b[1] for row_a, row_b in zip(arr1, arr2))
```

There's no such thing in pure python as "2-dim arrays", these are lists of lists.

```
   #    arr1         arr2
   [             [
    [1, 2, 3],     [9, 2, 8],
    [4, 5, 6],     [7, 5, 7],
    [7, 8, 9]      [3, 8, 1]
   ]             ]


   # zip(arr1, arr2)
   [
     #   row_a       row_b
     ( [1, 2, 3],  [9, 2, 8] ),
     ( [4, 5, 6],  [7, 5, 7] ),
     ( [7, 8, 9],  [3, 8, 1] )
   ]

   [
     #   row_a[1]   row_b[1]
     ( [ , 2,  ],  [ , 2,  ] ),
     ( [ , 5,  ],  [ , 5,  ] ),
     ( [ , 8,  ],  [ , 8,  ] )
   ]
```

- [`zip` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`all` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)